# Should user related data be part of a settings?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, user-behavior, settings

If I have an app that does something based on some information that user enters & can change - should those data be part of a settings?

For (dummy) example: if I have an app that creates reports based on my address that I enter at the first run, and can change latter (If I move to another city) -> is address in this case a valid field in settings page?

Or, we should consider as a setting only application behavior choices (such is - create this report in PDF or DOC format etc.)

What is best way to handle those data that application depends on, should be editable, but rarely changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information related to user I never expect in settings, it would be good if there will be profile or info option for that. For example, In gmail setting is different which don't have to do anything with personal information but it has profile option which contains all the personal information. Same is in the linkedin or facebook, there is profile option which contains all the informtion.

Answer (score 1):

The user account information can be part of a larger group called "Settings" if accurately identified as such - eg. Account and App Parameters accessed through a Settings main menu item.